# fixed header, page scrolls into header and hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header and footer with a height of 50px. However, when I scroll the page, the page content overlaps the fixed header and footer. How can I hide the page as it scrolls into the header and footer (the top 50px)?

This can only be done in HTML/CSS. If it takes JS or JQ to perform this, then I will forget about doing this.

CSS

```
 header {
   height: 50px;
   position: fixed;
 }

 .page {
   position: relative;
 }

 .sidebar {
   float: left;
   position: fixed;
   width: 220px;
 }

 .main {
   float: right;
   width: 740px;
 }

 footer {
   position: fixed;
   height: 50px;
 }
```

HTML

```
<header>
This content should stay on top.
</header>

<div class="page">
  <div class="sidebar">This content should not move when using scroll bars.</div>
  <div class="main"></div>
</div>

<footer>
This content should stay on bottom.
</footer>
```

Comment: <header>
This content should stay on top.
</head> - this might not solve it, but it's good to correct to </header>

Comment: Yup, typo with `</head>`. See if that fixes your problem (it should match your header element).

Comment: That was a typo here, and not on my actual html.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a value to your footer for example

```
bottom: 0;
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d7T83/

**EDIT**

Or you can specify a height for your page element

```
.page {
position: relative;
display:block;
height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: The elements stay fixed, however, main rolls over both header and footer still. It should appear as if it scrolls underneath it.

Comment: Not sure I get it right - but have you tried using z-indexes for that?

Comment: I rather not set a fixed height since visitors with a larger screen will see the page differently. I rather make the height fluid.

Comment: Just a final one and I'm out of ideas :) You can set a "min-height" so your element won't collapse, and can still be expanded if more content is added.

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/b45Tk/)**

css

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
header {
    top:0;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: #ccc;
    z-index:2;
}
.page {
    position: relative;
    background: #eee;
    z-index:1;
    height: 100%;
}
.sidebar {
    left:0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 220px;
    top:50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background: #ddd;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.main {
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 220px);
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    margin:50px 0;
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: #aaa;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the header, just give a margin top to the page content. For the footer and header Give them a z-index that is higher than the page div to ensure that it overlaps the content.

```
     header {
   height: 50px;
   position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:4;
    background-color:orange;
 }

 .page {
    margin-top:40px;

}



 .main {
   float: right;
   width: 740px;
 }

 footer {
     position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
   height: 50px;
    background-color:orange;
    z-index:4;
 }
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nathvarun/d7T83/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for would be this -

```
header {
  top: 0;
   height: 50px;
   position: fixed;
   display:block;             /* fill the width */
   z-index:2;                 /* z-index greater than .main */
   width:100%;                /* fill the width */
   background-color: white;   /* To make it opaque */
 }

 .page {
   position: relative;
 }

 .sidebar {
   top: 50px;
   float: left;
   position: fixed;
   width: 220px;
 }

 .main {
   margin-top: 50px;
   float: right;
   left: 220px;
   width: 740px;
   z-index:1;                /* z-index lesser than header and footer */
 }

  footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    display:block; /* fill the width */
    z-index:2;  /* z-index greater than .main */
    width:100%;  /* fill the width */
    background-color: white; /* To make it opaque */
  }
```

See example here - http://jsfiddle.net/7V57P/5/